# Visualforce remoting not working when iframed

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I have a VF page which is being used on a force.com site. It calls an apex method when the page is loaded using vf remoting. This is working fine when I open the URL directly in the browser. But when I try to use it in an iframe it throws the below error :

[image]

```
<script>

                function decodeEntity(inputStr) {
                        var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
                        textarea.innerHTML = inputStr;
                        return textarea.value;
                    };

                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

                    var calendarElement = document.getElementById('calendar');

                    var locale = '{!pageController.siteLanguage}';

                    if (locale) {
                        locale = locale.substring(0,2);
                    }
                    else {
                        locale = 'en';
                    }

                    console.log('locale='+locale);

                    calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarElement, {
                        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                        locale: locale,
                        headerToolbar: {
                            left: "prev,next today",
                            center: "title",
                            right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth"
                        },
                        buttonText: {
                            today:    '{!$Label.Site_Button_Today}',
                            month:    '{!$Label.Site_Button_Month}',
                            week:     '{!$Label.Site_Button_Week}',
                            day:      '{!$Label.Site_Button_Day}',
                            list:     '{!$Label.Site_Button_List}'
                        },
                        dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                        eventDataTransform: function(event) {
                            return  {
                                id: event.id,
                                title: decodeEntity(event.displayTitle),
                                start: event.startDate,
                                end: event.endDate,
                                display: 'auto',
                                allDay: event.allDay,
                                url: event.url,
                                overview: event.overview
                            };
                        },
                        events: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {

                            let encryptedContact = '{!pageController.EncryptedContact}';

                            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                                '{!$RemoteAction.EventHomeController.loadEvents}', 
                                organisingEntity, encryptedContact, filterSearchTerm, filterEventType, null,
                                function(results, event) { 
                                    successCallback(results);
                                }, 
                                { escape: true }
                            );
                        },
                        eventMouseEnter: function(info) {
                            //console.log('eventMouseEnter: ' + info.event.id + ' : ' + info.event.title);
                          
                            // code if we need to format the start date in future
                            // var str = info.view.calendar.formatDate(info.event.start, {
                            //     month: 'short',
                            //     year: 'numeric',
                            //     day: 'numeric'
                            // });

                            var title = info.event.title;
                            if (info.event.extendedProps.overview) {
                                title += '\r'+info.event.extendedProps.overview;
                            }

                            $( info.el ).css('cursor','pointer').attr('title', title);

                        },
                        eventMouseLeave: function(info) {
                            $( info.el ).css('cursor','auto');
                        }
                    }); 

                    calendar.render();

                
                });

                var applyEventFilters = () => {                         
                    filterEventType = $('#filterEventType').val(); 
                    filterSearchTerm = $('#filterSearchTerm').val(); 
                    calendar.refetchEvents();   
                };

                var resetEventFilters = () => {     
                    resetFilterFields();
                    calendar.refetchEvents();   
                }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apex Class that is being used as the controller class of the visualforce page and the Apex methods should be declared as `global`.

Visualforce Page:

```html
<apex:page controller="EventHomeController"...>
```

Apex Class:

```java
global with sharing class EventHomeController {
  @RemoteAction
  global static <returnType> loadEvents(<parameters>) {
    //method code
  }
}
```